# Not able to put date value from excel file into web application form

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am using excel file to import test data in web form. i have one field in the excel name as date and value is 12/01/2019 , but when i am using this value in selenium then i am getting below error.
`error : Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell.`

My code is

```
String Excel_Date=sheet1.getRow(4).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
```

i tried the same using `getdatecellvalue` still it is not working .

```
Date Excel_Date=sheet1.getRow(4).getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
```

could you please help me here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append `'` before each number in your excel sheet and then your code would work completely fine.
So if you have a value `12/01/2019`, you need to change it to `'12/01/2019` in the excel sheet and then use the method:

```
String Excel_Date=sheet1.getRow(4).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: HI Sameer, Thank you :) it is working fine now .thanks for the quick response